# How to create a multi-select listbox on a website?

Tags: javascript, html

Unfortunately, I don't know if this is the correct way to word what I am looking for.  Plotly is a graphical package for displaying data and it has the method I would like to use for a web form I am creating.  I do not know what language this would need to be written in, so I apologize in advance for that.  I am trying to create a webform that has a box that will hold selections or text inputs from a separate field.  I would like it to look like this: [Plotly multi-selection box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwa8K.png).

If possible I would like to do this in HTML, but I don't think that's possible.  I am assuming this will need to have some javascript.

Comment: This isn't a question, this is a vague product specification. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: He wants to do a multi selection in HTML for a form he is building: I do not understand the downvotes

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you need [something like this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp) that is pure HTML:

```
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Or using JavaScript [something like this](https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-multiselect-dropdown) that is a plugin that I think you need to buy. But maybe you can do it even with some other library that do not need to be purchased like jQuery for example.

Comment: Thanks, the javascript is the direction I will go with this.  Appreciate the help in finding the direction I need to search.